# eventdate to equal 01/07/2017

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have written this SQL below. I'm trying to get the 1st of July 2017. however, it's pulling through the 30th June and the 1st of July but can quite figure out what's wrong.

```
SELECT  
SubscriberKey
, JOBID
, EmailAddress
, Reason
, Date as EventDate
FROM Unsubscribes_2017 
WHERE DATE > dateadd(dd,-3,getdate()) 
AND DATE dateadd(dd, -2,getdate()) 
GROUP BY SubscriberKey, JOBID,
EmailAddress, Reason, Date
```

Comment: You can use the N_DAYS_AGO:N syntax. For this example, WHERE DATE = N_DAYS_AGO:2

Comment: Other options for relative date filters: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_dates.htm&language=en&type=0

Comment: Why don't you just hard Code the date into your where conditions?

Comment: @PeterHo this is t-sql so the Salesforce way won't work

Comment: Just hard coded it and it all works now. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The dates in SFMC have timestamps you have to address.  I generally try to make it sargable.  This is the fastest way I've found, since it removes the extra `dateadd()` functions.

```
SELECT  
SubscriberKey
, JOBID
, EmailAddress
, Reason
, convert(date, Date) as EventDate
FROM Unsubscribes_2017 
WHERE DATE >= convert(date, getDate()-3)
AND DATE < convert(date,getdate()-2) 
GROUP BY 
SubscriberKey
, JOBID
, EmailAddress
, Reason
, convert(date, Date)
```

I'm guessing you'll want to strip the times off of our dates for grouping.  Casting/converting to `date` resets the time to `00:00:00`

If you want to hardcode the dates, you can do this:

```
SELECT  
SubscriberKey
, JOBID
, EmailAddress
, Reason
, convert(Date, date) as EventDate
FROM Unsubscribes_2017 
WHERE DATE >= '2017-07-02'
AND DATE < '2017-07-03'
GROUP BY 
SubscriberKey
, JOBID
, EmailAddress
, Reason
, convert(date, Date)
```

Comment: Thanks, another quick question if I have a date that's a string value and I only want to extract the last 2 days. when I run a query it's failing. any ideas why this may be happening? basically, i'm using a where clause "where date >= dateadd(dd,-2,getdate()) and date <= getdate() "

Comment: Just adjust the date criteria in my first example.  it's selecting one day.